# remove laravel cache by asterix

Tags: laravel

I create cache like this:

```
    @foreach ($menu->items as $key => $item)
        <div class="{{ $itemclass or 'menu-item'}}">
            @switch($item->type)
                @case("CustomUrlItem")
                    <a href="{{ $item->meta }}">{{ $item->title }}</a>
                @break

                @case("PageItem")
                    @php
                        $page = Cache::rememberForever('menu-item-'.$item->meta, function() use($item) {
                            return Content::find($item->meta);
                        });
                    @endphp
                    <a href="{{ $page->slug }}">{{ $item->title }}</a>
                @break

            @endswitch
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

if we focus specifically on this part:

```
                @case("PageItem")
                    @php
                        $page = Cache::rememberForever('menu-item-'.$item->meta, function() use($item) {
                            return Content::find($item->meta);
                        });
                    @endphp
                    <a href="{{ $page->slug }}">{{ $item->title }}</a>
                @break
```

When I want to remove cache for all 'menu-item-*' how could I do that.

Right now if I want to remove cache for menu-item-*

```
Cache::forget('menu-item-1');
Cache::forget('menu-item-2');
Cache::forget('menu-item-3');
```

I would have to iterate through all of menu-item-1, menu-item-2 etc to remove them? Could I do something like this instead:

```
Cache::forget('menu-item-*');
```

And that would wipe out all of menu-item-* cache?

I am using Laravel 5.6 and file driver to save cached items.

Comment: You may want to read about cache tags - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/cache#cache-tags

Comment: yes thank you very much: Cache tags are not supported when using the file or database cache drivers. They are out of the question.

Comment: You may wish to update your question with more specifics in that case. Which driver are you using, which version of Laravel, etc.

Comment: updated, however I belive it's not possible what I want otherwise it would have been mentioned in docs or somebody would have answered already.

Comment: You are correct, it's not possible with the database driver. One option would be to override the `DatabaseStore::forget` function to use a `LIKE` comparison instead. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Cache/DatabaseStore.php#L212

Comment: yes that is good idea, but its only for database cache if I see correctly :) I would not like to get locked to one kind of cache, best solution would work for any cache type laravel offers. Thanks for your input, I've plused you :)

Comment: Well it'll not work with the current `FileStore` implementation, because this hashes the cache key for use as the file path. Therefore wildcard searches would be impossible. I think if you want a cover all solution, you're SOL.